# What is a logical condition for a while loop stops only when both are >= 100?

Tags: python, while-loop

Here are the instructions:
The following program is meant to simulate a sequence of coin flips. The goal of the program is to simulate enough coin flips until there have been at least 100 heads and 100 tails. However, there are errors in the program on exactly 3 lines of the code. Fix those 3 lines (and only those 3 lines) so that the program behaves as it should.

Here is my code so far:

```
import random

heads_count = 0
tails_count = 0
flips = []

while heads_count < 100 and tails_count < 100:

    flip = random.choice(['heads', 'tails'])
    flips.append(flip)
    if flip == 'heads':
        heads_count += 1
    else:
        tails_count += 1

print('heads:', heads_count)
print('tails:', tails_count)
print(flips)
```

I found 2 of the errors and I know the last one is in my while loop line, but I can't figure out what's wrong with this line? Anyone know of a logical condition for a while loop stops only when both are >= 100?

Comment: So - you know what will happen in the while loop if either `heads_count` or `tails_count` gets to 100. How might you modify this statement such that it only becomes false when both are >=100? Are other logic operators available maybe?

Comment: Yes, I got it with while heads_count < 100 or tails_count < 100. Such a simple error. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As written, the while loop breaks when either heads or tails reaches a total of 100. If heads_count = 100, but tails_count = 90, then the statement:

```
heads_count < 100 and tails_count < 100
```

will evaluate to false, even though tails_count hasn't hit 100 yet. There are other solutions, like creating a "done" variable which is set equal to True and at the end of each iteration you check to see if both counts are >= 100, but if you need one line of code you should use an OR statement, like:

```
while heads_count < 100 OR tails_count < 100:
```

This evaluates to True until both of them are >= 100, when it will evaluate to False, and break the loop.